# How can I find a scalable font with a relatively large x height?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, drop-cap

I am in the middle of a book, typesetting it with pdflatex, and I am in search of a scalable font with a relatively large x height with the ultimate goal of using this font for drop caps. Is there a way to know if a font is scalable from the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html)?

Edit for clarification: I am really only considering serif fonts (unless something terrible happens or someone convinces me otherwise). The main concern for the scalable font is for drop caps (meaning that I will be using that for capital letters), but the font should have a relatively large x height overall for the main body of the text. (This is a breviary.)

Comment: Are you willing to consider any and all fonts, or does it have to be a serif (or a sans-serif) font? A separate concern: The term "drop caps" suggests (implies?) that uppercase letters are used in drop-cap applications. Thuss, why care about a font's x-height, which is meaningful mainly (exclusively?) for lowercase letters? Please clarify.

Comment: there are very few fonts that are not scalable these days, just try it with pdflatex and look at the log, if it gives a path ending in `.pk` it is bitmap, anything else it is scalable